# What are the best hours to sleep?

Tags: sleep

I've read stuff about your body producing certain hormones and getting rid of certain stuff at specific hours. Also not sure if these hours are affected by sunlight/apartment lights.

What would be the best hours to be sleeping?

Answer (score 4):

There are many evidences that a good night's sleep is the hallmark to have good health. Ideally you should go to bed between 10 pm and midnight and wake up when you feel like getting up in the morning. By following this habit you can complete your sleep and wake up fresh.

**It's some Facts of Sleeping:**

1. Sleep is vital to your well-being, as important as the air you
   breathe, the water you drink and the food you eat. It can even help
   you to eat better and manage the stress of being a teen.
2. Biological sleep patterns shift toward later times for both sleeping
   and waking during adolescence -- meaning it is natural to not be
   able to fall asleep before 11:00 pm.
3. Teens need about 8 to 10 hours of sleep each night to function best.
   Most teens do not get enough sleep — one study found that only 15%
   reported sleeping 8 1/2 hours on school nights.
4. Teens tend to have irregular sleep patterns across the week — they
   typically stay up late and sleep in late on the weekends, which can
   affect their biological clocks and hurt the quality of their sleep.
   [image]